# Simple Dendrogram in R with first data column as labels

Tags: r, label, dendrogram

I created a dendrogram in R with the command below...

I have been trying to find the command to replace the number with the name of the County which is the first column in the data set or load the plot with the name of the county instead of the number.  If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

```
hc = hclust(dist(NYCounty))
plot(hc)
```

[image: The current plot]

[image: The data of NYCounty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it to `labels` argument in `plot.hclust`. A reproducible example showing this:

```
# example from ?hclust
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc)
# custom labels
df <- data.frame(foo=paste("hi", 1:50))
plot(hc, labels=df$foo)
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: not really... that just added the word "hi" proceeding the number, I was looking for this... I created the image in photoshop and not R.  I replaced the numbers with the names of the county in the cluster.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8256776/Dendrogram.png

Comment: well ok, but can't you change `df$foo` with your own column?

Comment: thanks... I needed this command plot(hcc, labels=NYCounty$County)